# ListBox Item layout in XAML/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am struggling last days to achieve following layout:

[image: sketch]

I have a ListBox with template for each Item:

- Label always anchored on left side
- Label always anchored on right side
- Label (TextBlock) in middle with flexible size
- 3rd label bellow, so far this is easiest to set :)

Main problem in my example is that I can't made middle text (that can be long) to adjust, but not push suffix (red) label while I am resizing ListBox.

I hope that this layout is possible, and that I am missing something trivial.

What's interesting is that 1st example (bellow) work well "outside" listbox. Do I need somehow force realign of listbox while resizing?

Thanks for any help.

I have attached bellow 2 examples I tried (beside many other):

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Experiments.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Experiments"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Blue" Background="Aqua" Content="{Binding Prefix}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Description}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="2" Foreground="Magenta" Background="Beige" Content="{Binding Suffix}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="Template2">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Foreground="Blue" Background="Aqua" Content="{Binding Prefix}" />
                <Label Grid.Column="2" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Foreground="Magenta" Background="Beige" Content="{Binding Suffix}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox Name="MyListBox"
                 ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Template2}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
namespace WPF_Experiments
{
    class Item
    {
        public string Prefix { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Suffix { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
            items.Add(new Item() { Prefix = "001", Description = "Item 0", Suffix = "cm" });
            items.Add(new Item() { Prefix = "002", Description = "This is very long item that maybe will not fit", Suffix = "in" });
            items.Add(new Item() { Prefix = "003", Description = "Item 2", Suffix = "m" });
            MyListBox.ItemsSource = items;
        }
    }
}
```

(Edit) One more try with StackPanel:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template3">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Foreground="Blue" Background="Aqua" Content="{Binding Prefix}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
            <Label Foreground="Magenta" Background="Beige" Content="{Binding Suffix}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Instead of using a grid inside your listbox try using a stackpanel

Comment: Unfortunately not worked (I have added Template3 above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by disabling horizontal scrolling for `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Template2}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is it.